Active Directory in Springboot 3
I am trying to migrate an old code based on Springboot 2.1 to Spring 3.0.8.
This includes AD integration in it. Now the AD code in Springboot 2.1 was working fine, but as soon as I migrated to Springboot 3, it stopped working and started showing
org.springframework.ldap.InvalidNameException: [LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN]
even though I haven't made any changes to the AD side.
Here is my old code -
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domain,
                ldapUrls, ldapBaseDn);
        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

        if (ldapUserDnPattern != null && ldapUserDnPattern.trim().length() > 0) {
            adProvider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={1}))");
            // adProvider.setSearchFilter(ldapUserDnPattern);
        }

        auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);
        auth.eraseCredentials(false);

    }

My new code doesnt have much changes , as suggested by various documents.
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider =
                new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domain, ldapUrls,ldapBaseDn);
        
 
        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        adProvider.setSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={1}))");

        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(adProvider);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();

I tried to implement various strategies and implementations but it didn't work.
I cannot share my domain, ldapUrls and ldapBaseDn due to company policy but they have been the same throughout the process and i checked using Apache Directory Studio my code configurations are correct.

This may seem like a direct answer but the there might be an issue with the ldapBaseDn parameter which you are passing.
The syntax might be invalid. here
The post is very old.
Additionally, I have integrated LDAP with Spring 3.x
CODE FOR REFERENCE
WebSecurityConfig Beans
@Bean
public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(){
    return new LdapTemplate(ldapContextSource());
}
@Bean
public LdapContextSource ldapContextSource(){
    LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    ldapContextSource.setPassword(pass);
    ldapContextSource.setUrl(url);
    ldapContextSource.setUserDn(userDn);
    return ldapContextSource;
}

 @Bean
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) throws Exception {
    LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory ldapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory =
            new LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory(contextSource);
    ldapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory.setUserSearchBase(searchBase);
    ldapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory.setUserSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={1}))");
    return ldapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory.createAuthenticationManager();
}

This may be helpful
Please mark the answer as correct if this helps

The answer just provide another way of writing the same code. Need to highlight how this answer can solve the problem
